# Twitter API status update always returns "Incorrect signature"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, twitter, oauth, signpost

I'm using [Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) as OAuth implementation for posting to Twitter. And implemented the `GoogleAppEngineOAuthConsumer` and `GoogleAppEngineOAuthProvider` classes, but since they're pretty trivial, so I'm not providing their sources here (yet).

Here's my authentication part, which seems to work just fine.

LoginServlet.java:

```
// fetching the request token
OAuthConsumer consumer = new GoogleAppEngineOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
OAuthProvider provider = new GoogleAppEngineOAuthProvider(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, AUTHORIZATION_URL);
String redirectUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
// cache the request token and request token secret
response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

CallbackServlet.java

```
// fetching the access token
String verifier = (String) req.getParameter("oauth_verifier");
// retrieve request token and request token secret from cache
OAuthConsumer consumer = new GoogleAppEngineOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
OAuthProvider provider = new GoogleAppEngineOAuthProvider(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, 
consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, tokenSecret);
provider.setOAuth10a(true);
provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);
// store access token and access token secret
```

And here's the actual problematic part.

TweetServlet.java

```
OAuthConsumer consumer = new GoogleAppEngineOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
// retrieve access token and access token secret from storage
consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
final HTTPRequest updateStatus = new HTTPRequest(new URL("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"), HTTPMethod.POST);
updateStatus.setPayload(("status=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")).getBytes());
consumer.sign(updateStatus);
logger.debug(new String(URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(updateStatus).getContent()));
```

Each and every time it results: `{"request":"/1/statuses/update.json","error":"Incorrect signature"}`.

Comment: I've figured out that this could relate to the way I send the parameters, since when I change the `TweetServlet` to `final HTTPRequest updateStatus = new HTTPRequest(new URL("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json"), HTTPMethod.GET);` it returns proper response.

Comment: That would've been my next take if I hadn't got this working. I chose not to do that in the first place, since I would be only using small subset of it and secondly that I might use this as a basis for other services based on OAuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by myself. The problem was that I wasn't setting a `Content-Type` header to the request, so the signing didn't sign the parameters and it resulted the invalid signature. Once I set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it started working.

```
final HTTPRequest updateStatus = new HTTPRequest(new URL("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"), HTTPMethod.POST);
updateStatus.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```